# Redis cache exception while try to access data from redis "invalid bulk length"

Tags: spring, caching, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using Redis for cache management. Randomly I am facing issue, while I tried to access the cache data, please see the below exception.

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Protocol error: invalied bulk length
org.sprintframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: ERR Protocol error: invalid bulk length; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Protocol error: invalid bulk length
  at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.jedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:69)
```

I am unable to trace out the root cause...

Comment: Although, I am not a Redis expert, at first glance, are you sure your Redis (Jedis) client driver and Redis server are compatible with each other? Whenever I see a "Protocol" error, or a communication error, I suspect a client/server version problem. It could also mean that the Redis client driver API (Jedis) was not properly used in a Spring (Caching) context or that the data you stored in Redis concurrently changed in some way affecting Spring's caching infra. Do you have an example repo you could share that reproduces the problem? I'd be happy to take a look in this case. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnBlum Thanks for your reply. Since it is a private repo, I am unable to share the repo details.

i can provide the version details
Spring boot Version 2.6.7
JAVA 1.8
spring data redis 2.6.4
jedis 3.6.1